# OpenGL ES 2D Co-Ordinates

Tags: android, opengl-es, 2d

I'm trying to set up my GLSurfaceView to use traditional 2D coordinate system.
Basically, I want to put my first tile at 0x0 which would be at the top left.
However, when I draw my texture at 0x0 it draws it at the bottom left.

I want it to start at 0x0 and go down as the Y co-ordinate increases.

Here's how I'm initializing my renderer:

```
gl.glClearColor(0f, 0f, 0f, 1);
gl.glViewport(0, 0, mViewWidth,mViewHeight); 
gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
gl.glLoadIdentity();

GLU.gluOrtho2D(gl, 0, mViewWidth, mViewHeight, 0);

gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
gl.glLoadIdentity();

gl.glHint(GL10.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL10.GL_FASTEST);
gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_BLEND);
gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
gl.glBlendFunc(GL10.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL10.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
gl.glShadeModel(GL10.GL_FLAT);
gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

And I draw my texture using:

```
gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, mytexture);
((GL11Ext) gl).glDrawTexfOES(0, 32, 0, tile_width, tile_height);
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve this by @datenwolf's comment.

The basic initialization was correct, however using glDrawTexOES ignores the ortho camera.
To avoid using glDrawTex I loaded the textures as usual but used a vertex buffer to draw them.

I used the SpriteMethodTest android project which contains code on how to load them properly.
I simply had to play with the camera and everything works ok now.

Answer (score 5):

It draws at the bottom left, because that's where OpenGL defines the viewport origin to be. To overcome this you must mirror the Y axis in the projection. Easy enough, just swap the *bottom* and *top* parameters of glOrtho.

```
GL.glOrtho(gl, 0, mViewWidth, mViewHeight, 0, -1, 1); // using GL. instead of GLU
```

Comment: Thanks, but no luck.  I don't see GL.glOrthof as a static method, but I used: gl.glOrthof(0, mViewWidth, 0, mViewHeight, -1, 1); (instead of GLU) and it's still drawing the texture at the bottom left.

Comment: Still nothing, I changed it to this: gl.glOrthof(0, mViewWidth, mViewHeight, 0, -1, 1);
What I find odd is that even if I remove the glOrtho call if I draw the texture to 0,0 it still shows up in the bottom left instead of the center of the screen.  Perhaps it's glDrawTex that's doing something

Comment: Argh, I always forget that on OpenGL-ES people are seduced by DrawTex. That one doesn't care about the projection, it takes screen coordinates. Exchange it with drawing a textured quad.

Comment: Ah ha, so that's what it is.  I'll go ahead and try this out.

Comment: @Miguel And also keep in mind that this flipping in glOrtho effectively flips the orientation of your primitives. So you should either pay attention to correct orientation or disable face culling at all (disabled by default).

Comment: @Christian: Thanks, I actually ran into this and kept in mind what you said.  Everything is working ok now, thanks!